# Visual studio Map file for x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, name-mangling

In visual studio for an x86 (win32 release) when building a project I am able to create a map file by doing the below configuration

project properties>> Linker >> Debugging >> Generate Map file = yes.

[image]

How do I Generate the map file for x64 builds as in the project properties I am not able to see the Debugging option to generate map.

[image]

Are there no map files that can be generated for x64 if so could anyone explain why the debugging options in visual studio is present only for x86 builds.

Comment: It is there for x64. Judging by the fact you don't have "C/C++" on the left, it looks like you you have the wrong project selected.

Comment: @ChrisMM  am in the same project I open the project properties window and in that the menu options change as in the screenshots when I change platform from win32 -> win64

Comment: Try setting x64 from outside the properties window, on the main VS tool bar.

Comment: It's there for me in Win32, x64, and All Platforms. I agree with @ChrisMM, the left side does not look correct for a C++ project.

Comment: When I changed compiler and changed it bacj now i can see it for win32 and x64 seems like a slight bug or some issue at my end, I am not able to reproduce it.